# Which character in the Arrowverse has been killed the most times?

Tags: dc, arrowverse

There's a running joke among fans of *Arrow* and *Legends of Tomorrow* about how many times Sara Lance dies, but is she actually the character with the most deaths?

For purposes of this question, I'm counting a death as any time that an unbiased coroner or similar medical professional would have declared the character dead (even if they were resurrected too quickly for such a medical investigation) or they were officially declared dead in the absence of a body and they did not have a prior plan to fake their own death. I'm also counting any time that a character was erased from existence. Doppelgangers would count as different characters.

I've seen a few answers on other sites, but they don't seem up-to-date.

Comment: _"I'm counting a death any time that a character was wounded in a way that an in-universe character would reasonably think killed them"_ -> So you're counting "deaths" that aren't actually deaths and never were?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot, yes. I'm wondering how many times their friends think they died. Does that seem unreasonable?

Comment: In real life, we technically say someone died if their heart stopped for an extended period of time, even if they were brought back by a medical intervention. It's harder to tell if this happens when there's do much magic around in some settings.

Comment: That's an important distinction though, are you going for the heart stop deaths counting or X was gravely wounded but disappeared from view so he might be dead deaths counting?

Comment: Or even the Disney "surely no one could have survived that" deaths where someone falls out of a helicopter but is later shown to have landed in the National Foam Rubber Convention?

Comment: Ages ago, I read a newspaper article about a convict with a life sentence who made the following appeal in court: "My heart stopped during surgery. That means I was dead. The fact that the doctors managed to restart it should not negate the fact that when I died on the operating table, my life sentence came to an end, and now I should be a free man!" (The judge disagreed with his interpretation.)

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot, I attempted to clarify. Still not entirely sure if it makes sense to consider deaths where we don't see a body or not.

Comment: @ FuzzyBoots are you sure someone fell out of a helicopter? I remember the Bat copter in the 1960s TV series landing on foam rubber at the Foam Rubbers Wholesalers Convention.

Comment: Ra’s Al Ghul died the most (unknown). Followed by Oliver Queen (thrice)